# SQL Pivot - Union 2 queries

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following query that creates a pivot table with the first row presenting the cloth size's: S, M, L and XL.

```
SELECT * 
FROM (SELECT 
        [LOC],
        [QUANTITY],
        [SIZE]
  FROM [TABLE]

  WHERE [Item]= '123456') s 

  PIVOT (SUM([QUANTITY]) FOR [SIZE] IN ([S],[M],[L],[XL])) pvt
```

Resulting in:

```
  LOC       S   M   L   XL
  USA       2   2   1
  EUR       1   2   2   1
  ASIA      1   2   2   1
```

Because some products have different sizing tables (for example: Men have: S,M,L. Women have: 36,38,40), I want to combine the above query with this one, which shows the available sizes for that specified product.
So the first row is based on the available sizing from the Table-Sizing.

```
  SELECT * FROM [TABLE-Sizing] WHERE [Item] = '123'
```

Results:

```
  34
  36
  38
```

I hope someone can help me!

Thanks!

[EDIT1]
I tried to use UNION with the second query, but don't know what to insert in the last line to use that:

```
SELECT * 
FROM (SELECT 
        [LOC],
        [QUANTITY],
        [SIZE]
  FROM [TABLE]

  WHERE [Item]= '123456')
  UNION
  SELECT [SIZE]
  FROM [TABLE-SIZING] s 

  PIVOT (SUM([QUANTITY]) FOR [SIZE] IN (?????)) pvt
```

Comment: Search this site for "dynamic pivot" or "dynamic cross tab". This has been asked and answered many times.

Comment: Your question is unclear without sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like mentioned you first need a list of possibilities:

I would union all of that into a cte and use that in place of table in the stuff statement

```
--I used a classic stuff technique combined with quotename which brackets the answers

declare @possibilities varchar(max);
;with cte as (
select distinct size from table
union all
select distinct size from [different table]
)
select @possibilities = stuff( (select distinct ','+QUOTENAME(SIZE) from cte for xml path(''))
                ,1,1,'')

--Now create dynamic SQL

declare @sql varchar(max);
set @sql = 
'SELECT * 
FROM (SELECT 
        [LOC],
        [QUANTITY],
        [SIZE]
  FROM [TABLE]

  WHERE [Item]= '123456') s 

  PIVOT (SUM([QUANTITY]) FOR [SIZE] IN ('

+ @possibilities
+ ') pvt'

EXECUTE(@sql)
```